# C#: Why is this object not modified after the function is executed?

Tags: c#

I always thought that objects where always passed as reference in C# and that if a function modifies it then the parent method should have a modified version of that object. However, reading this code that was left by an old developer that was causing a bug makes me think that this is not always the case. The code is the following:

```
Item item = new Item();
PopulateItem(sodItem, id, item);
```

The function code is the following:

```
private void PopulateItem(eSodTypes.Item sodItem, int id, Item item)
        {

                if (sodItem != null)
                {
                    item = (Item)sodItem;
                    item.Delivery = (Delivery)sodItem.Delivery;
                    if (sodItem.Delivery != null)
                    {
                        item.Delivery.DeliveryContact = (CustomerContact)sodItem.Delivery.DeliveryContact;
                        item.Delivery.DeliveryAddress = (Address)sodItem.Delivery.DeliveryAddress;
                        item.Delivery.ShippingInstructions = (ShippingInstructions)sodItem.Delivery.ShippingInstructions;
                    }
                    item.Installation = (Installation)sodItem.Installation;
                    item.Training = (Training)sodItem.Training;
                    item.Service = (Service)sodItem.Service;
                    item.Service.Address = (Address)sodItem.Service.Address;
                    if (sodItem.Service.Address != null)
                        item.Service.Address.Contact = (CustomerContact)sodItem.Service.Address.Contact;
                    item.Service.Customer = (Customer)sodItem.Service.Customer;
                    if (sodItem.ItemLines != null)
                        item.ItemLines = sodItem.ItemLines.Items.ToList().ConvertAll(new Converter<eSodTypes.ItemLine, ItemLine>(ItemLine.ItemLineTypeToItemLineTypeModel));
                }
        }
```

If I use "ref" with the item it works, but I thought this was only for value types like "int" or "double".

Comment: Are you sure that Item is a class and not a struct ?

Comment: Where is Jon Skeet when you need him...

Comment: If `Item` was a class, `item = (Item)sodItem` would only create a shallow copy - that is, both variables would be pointing to the same area in memory and subsequent `item.Delivery = (Delivery)sodItem.Delivery` etc. would be redundant. Also, changing "original" `sodItem` will result in modifying `item` which probably is not what you want. Making a deep copy of an object requires rewriting it property after property (and deep copying these properties as well, if they're classes). There's some tricks available such as using reflection or serialization, but they have drawbacks of their own.

Comment: Doesn't matter whether it's class or struct: the code doesn't modify the value that's passed in, it assigns a new value to `item` right at the start.  The parameter would need to be a `ref` parameter to follow the change, whether it's class *or* struct.

Comment: The code is somewhat broken in any case. First a new item is initialized and then a reference to sodItem is set. Seems a candidate for refactoring for me...

Comment: I always thought of C# as passing by value unless you use the `ref` keyword or the `out` keyword.  With reference types you're passing references by value types you're passing values by value.

Comment: @Yves M: He already wrote [an article on this](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean that you expect that 'item' will be modified upon return from the method.  The problem is here:

```
item = (Item)sodItem;
```

You're modifying the variable item to point to the parameter sodItem, so it's no longer pointing to the same item that was passed in.  The original reference 'item' was never modified.  When you change the item parameter to 'ref', this does cause the original reference of the variable passed as a parameter to change.

Note that this current code is actually modifying the original sodItem (copying its own values back to itself), which might not be your intention.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the reason. Why we are doing this? Well we have two set of objects in the project. The old ones (where sodItems) come from used by the old system and "Item" which is the object used by the new one that is based on the old system. Since the company just wants to modify the presentation layer we have to make a "transformation" to this new objects that include some changes that would break the old system. Some developer liked doing this "transformation" by overloading the explicit operator. Works good, but it seems it has its gotchas. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Same conclusion here.  Just looked for the first line of the code where he was setting the variable to something else.  :)

Comment: @groovejet, that's a very unintuitive use of the explicit cast operator, particularly since this is a reference type.  I recognize that such things are difficult to change, but I would recommend flagging it as a high-risk item for long-term maintenance costs.

Comment: +1 @Dan: Same happens to me, I am using ref in this param object, Now its working fine, I just want to know if its a good practise.

Answer (score 15):

I have a piece of paper with an address on it: 123 Sesame Street. I hand you a photocopy of that piece of paper.

You proceed to 123 Sesame Street and find a blue house. You paint the house green.

You then cross out 123 Sesame Street on your photocopy and replace it with 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue.

*My* piece of paper with the address on it does not change.  I go to 123 Sesame Street, and sure enough, the house is now green.

You see?  The *house* was "passed by reference" when I made my photocopy. The piece of paper is not a house; it is a reference to a house. A copy of that reference is *still* a reference to the house. Changing one reference does not change any other reference; changing *the colour of the thing referred to* changes that colour for all references.

Suppose by contrast *I share my piece of paper with you instead of making a copy*. Now if you scratch out 123 Sesame Street and replace it with 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, I see the change because we are *sharing* the same reference.  You *share a variable* with a method by using the "ref" keyword.

Make sense?

Comment: Great analogy! What happens then if your class sets a property to another object (eg. MyProperty = someOtherInstantiatedObject). Now, if MyProperty is modified, why do I not see the changes in someOtherInstantiatedObject? Should they not be the thing/Object? How would you do it? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You will have to use the ref keyword to get this to work. The difference is subtle ... when you pass an object the pointer is passed by value .. ie it is copied. So now you have two pointer pointing to the same thing. When you then assign a new object to the parameter pointer you do not affect the original pointer .. its still points to the original.

When you use ref the pointer is literally passed so if you reassign it then the original pointer is also reassigned.

More info here ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx

To make yours work you will either ...

a) need to use the ref keyword or 
b) do this item = (Item)sodItem; before passing it to the method

Comment: Here's another link that explains this quite clearly ... skip down to the reference parameters section ... http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html